While using groq for my project im getting this error
def claim_agent(user_question):
    memory = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(ai_prefix="Insurance Agent", k=20)
    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=['history', 'input'],
        template="""
            You are a Insurance agent bot, you have to talk with our customers and collect all the required details to fill the claim:
            "Policy_number":
            "Cause_of_accident":
            "Contacted_Police/Fire_department":
            "Report_Number":
            "Street_number":
            "Street_name":
            "City":
            "State_Province":
            "Zip_Code":
            "Country":
            "Loss_date":
            "time":
            Make sure to ask only one at a time and also make your responses align with the customer sentiment. Make sure collect all the above data,
            After collecting all the data provide the output in a json format which has all the above mentioned values and make sure to provide the time in 24hr format and also date in American format.
            and say thank you for providing all the details our we will assign an adjuster to process the claim!.
            conversation history:
            {history}
            human:{input}
            AI:
            """
    )
    conversation_chain = LLMChain(
        llm=Llama3_8b,
        prompt=prompt_template,
        memory=memory,
    )
    query=user_question
    verification="False"
    while True:
        response = conversation_chain.invoke(query)
        print("Agent: ", response['text'])
        if '{' in response['text']:
            break
        query = input("You: ")
    data = memory.load_memory_variables({})
    conversation = []
    for key, value in data.items():
        conversation.append([key + ':' + value])
    complete_data = list(conversation[0][0].split('\n'))
    conversation_data = ''
    for i in complete_data:
        conversation_data += " " + i
    return conversation_data
User_question=input("Please enter your query: ")
claim_agent(User_question)

For this code im getting error like this:
Please enter your query: Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Project_tests\AI Chat Agent\test.py", line 65, in 
claim_agent(User_question)
File "D:\Project_tests\AI Chat Agent\test.py", line 50, in claim_agent
response = conversation_chain.invoke(query)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 163, in invoke
raise e
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 153, in invoke
self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py", line 103, in _call
response = self.generate([inputs], run_manager=run_manager)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py", line 115, in generate
return self.llm.generate_prompt(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 560, in generate_prompt
return self.generate(prompt_messages, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 421, in generate
raise e
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 411, in generate
self._generate_with_cache(
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\chat_models.py", line 632, in _generate_with_cache
result = self._generate(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_groq\chat_models.py", line 242, in _generate
response = self.client.create(messages=message_dicts, **params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq\resources\chat\completions.py", line 178, in create
return self._post(
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 1194, in post
return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 896, in request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 972, in _request
return self._retry_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 1020, in _retry_request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 972, in _request
return self._retry_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 1020, in _retry_request
return self._request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Project_tests.venv\Lib\site-packages\groq_base_client.py", line 987, in _request
raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
groq.InternalServerError: Error code: 503 - {'error': {'message': 'Service Unavailable', 'type': 'internal_server_error'}}
Im trying to pass a input query to groq but it is raising an error! it worked well until 1 hr before but suddenly it started generating this type of errors! I even tried chaging the api key but still the issue persisting! If i directly use the langchain "Invoke method" and pass a simple prompt directly within it, it is generating an output so i think the issue is not about the rate limit or any other things!!

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Hey i am getting the same error, 503 error indicates that the server is down for maintenance/Overload => source:  https://console.groq.com/docs/errors
A few of their API servers might be down for maintenance/ upgrade/ servicing , therefore it might be better if you wait for sometime ( probably a day ~ 24 hrs. ) till they fix it up
i don't think anything is wrong with your code. Another alternative is to replace groq with another provider of the API with replicate or Together or OpenRouter ( it think openRouter has a free tier for a few models).
